# Create Two UILabels dynamically using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uilabel, custom-cell

In one array I have one string and one more array I want to display this dynamically in custom cell. My array structure is given below. It will change according to data coming from web service.

```
{
subDescription =     (
    "Worship Hours 5.00am to 12.30pm & 4.00pm to 10.00pm",
    "The temple is open all days of the week"
);
subHeading = Hours;
}
```

And i tried like this using this format i can display `subHeading` Value only how to display `subDescription` array

```
float xCoordinate=10.0,yCoordinate=30.0,width=320,height=40;
float ver_space=20.0;

for (int i = 0; i <test.count; i++)
{
  NSDictionary *lanuage=[test objectAtIndex:i]; 
  NSString *work=[lanuage objectForKey:@"subHeading"];
  NSArray *er=[lanuage objectForKey:@"subDescription"];

  UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:   
  CGRectMake(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,width,height)];

  label.text = work;
  [events.contentView addSubview:label]; 
  yTCoordinate=yTCoordinate+heightT+ver_space;
}
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading. Do you want to create two labels dynamically or you are facing problem to retrieve subDescription ???

Comment: I want to create two labels dynamically ,fetching it's okay for me. After creating subHeading i need display subDescription array elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand, but why dont you use CollectionView instead of a label. There you can define header cell and sub cells. I think this fits your problem.

In case that you do not want to use collection view you can adjust your code and iterate with loop through your sub items array.

```
    for (NSString *item in er) {
       UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:   
       CGRectMake(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,width,height)];

       label.text = item;
       [events.contentView addSubview:label]; 
       yCoordinate=yCoordinate+height+ver_space; 
    }
```